# What word or expression can I use for a new employee?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

What would be the best word, or expression, for a new employee who has just joined the organization?

Would 'joinee' be a suitable word that I can use?

Comment: Currently, "new hire" and "new employee" are in use and widely understood. These phrases are also used by the US government. "Joinee" is not a word.

Comment: 'Pleb' or 'FNG' for military uses.

Comment: ***Very*** informally, “newbie”, which is even more informally abbreviated to “noob”.

Answer (score 6):

***New hire*** is probably what you're looking for. While there are other terms that you may see or hear used, many of them have other connotations:

***Trainee*** suggests that the person lacks necessary knowledge or experience, and that a significant purpose of the inclusion in the organization is to provide that training and experience. This is not appropriate, for example, in the case where the person is first joining your organization, but has significant experience and knowledge in the organization's field of endeavor.

***Rookie*** also carries the implication of lack of experience, and, as with *trainee*, is not appropriate for an experienced individual joining your organization. This is also viewed as a colloquial expression, and may be inappropriate, even if accurate, in business situations.

***Greenhorn***, like *rookie*, carries connotations of lack of experience, and usually knowledge as well, and is also colloquial.

***Fresh meat*** is not only colloquial, it is disrespectful of both the newly-hired individual and the organization (and its culture). The implication is that the newly-hired individual doesn't know what s/he is getting into (and likely has expectations that are, at least for the organization, unrealistic), and is likely to be treated poorly, possibly verging on professional abuse - and the professional abuse is considered a part of the organizational culture (whether desirable or not).

Comment: A new employee/ new hire need not be a trainee, rookie, greenhorn or fresh meat -- a company may even induct a new CFO, who would be a new employee. OTOH, "new hire" is as much a phrase as "new employee."

Comment: @Kris - in which case he'd still be a "new hire". That was more-or-less my point.

Comment: What's the issue with "new employee" then?

Comment: @Kris - None at all, from my point of view - but the OP originally sought an alternative term; the phrase "new employee" was specifically used in the question.